# How to improve vectorized sliding window for big data?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, vectorization

I need to use a sliding window in python on a time series with 6 million time steps and 8 features per time step. I created an array of sliding windows using both a vectorized version and a version with a for loop. The for loop is substantially faster. I have highlighted the time consuming step in the vectorized version. Is there a good way to speed up the vectorized version?

Here is the vectorized version:

```
def vectorized_window(T, l: int, stride=1, start_idxs=None, output_type="data"):
    """Takes a time series, T, and breakes it into subsequences of length l.

    This is a vectorized version of window creation. It should run faster because it uses
    matrix operations but for very large data, this is not true because the indexing operation
    at the end is slow.

    Args:
        T: A np.ndarray of shape (|T|, features) where |T| is the number of time steps.
        l: An int designating the length of the window.
        stride: The number of time steps to move the window forward by. Default is
            1 time step.
        start_idxs: A ndarray or None (default). If start_idxs is specified, these will be used as the start
            indices for each window. stride will be ignored. Default of None will
            sequentially slide the window by stride steps. Shape should be (num of indices,)
        output_type: "data" or "idxs". The default of "data" will compute and return the full window (ndarray)
            with the actual data values for each time step. If "idxs" is specified, it will return a ndarray
            of shape (num windows, 2) where windows[:,0] are the start indices and windows[:,1] are the end indices.

    Returns:
        windows: a list of ndarrays that represent windows, with length l, of the time series. The shape is
            either (num windows, l, num features) or (num windows, 2) depending on output_type.
    """
    window_idxs = np.expand_dims(np.arange(l), 0)
    if output_type != "data":
        window_idxs = window_idxs[[0, -1]]
    if start_idxs is None:
        start_idxs = np.expand_dims(np.arange(T.shape[0]-l, step=stride), 0).T
    else:
        start_idxs = np.expand_dims(start_idxs, 0).T
    
    if output_type != "data":
        windows = window_idxs + start_idxs
    else:
        sub_windows = (window_idxs + start_idxs)
        windows = T[sub_windows] # This is the slow step
    return windows
```

Here is the version with the for loop:

```
def create_window(T, l: int, stride=1):
    """Takes a time series, T, and breakes it into subsequences of length l.

    Args:
        T: A list or np.ndarray representing a univariate or multivariate time series.
            If it is a multivarite time series, it must be a numpy array of shape
            (time steps, features). If features is in axis 0, this will not work.
        l: An int designating the length of the window.
        stride: The number of time steps to move the window forward by. Default is
            1 time step.

    Returns:
        windows: a list of ndarrays that represent windows, with length l, of the time series.
    """
    if "list" in str(type(T)):
        T = np.asarray(T)

    n_T= T.shape[0]
    windows = []

    for i in range(0, n_T - l, stride):
        window = T[i:i+l]
        windows.append(window)
    
    return windows
```

The two versions don't do quite the same thing. The vectorized version will also return the bounding indices for each subsequence if the output_type is not "data". But, that difference does not significantly impact the overall speed.

Any suggestions to optimize this code is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [tsflex](https://github.com/predict-idlab/tsflex), this package has **[a very efficient](https://predict-idlab.github.io/tsflex/#benchmark) window-stride feature extraction**.

You can calculate your 8 features very conveniently, e.g., see [this example](https://github.com/predict-idlab/tsflex#usage):

```py
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np; import scipy.stats as ss
from tsflex.features import MultipleFeatureDescriptors, FeatureCollection

# 1. -------- Get your time-indexed data --------
url = "https://github.com/predict-idlab/tsflex/raw/main/examples/data/empatica/"
# Contains 1 column; ["TMP"] - 4 Hz sampling rate
data_tmp = pd.read_parquet(url+"tmp.parquet").set_index("timestamp")
# Contains 3 columns; ["ACC_x", "ACC_y", "ACC_z"] - 32 Hz sampling rate
data_acc = pd.read_parquet(url+"acc.parquet").set_index("timestamp")

# 2. -------- Construct your feature collection --------
fc = FeatureCollection(
    MultipleFeatureDescriptors(
          functions=[np.min, np.max, np.mean, np.std, np.median, ss.skew, ss.kurtosis],
          series_names=["TMP", "ACC_x", "ACC_y"], # Use 3 multimodal signals 
          windows=["5min", "7.5min"],  # Use 5 minutes and 7.5 minutes 
          strides="2.5min",  # With steps of 2.5 minutes
    )
)

# 3. -------- Calculate features --------
fc.calculate(data=[data_tmp, data_acc])
```

**Note**: tsflex requires that your data has a time-index, and that the window & stride (= step) arguments are time-based (e.g., "1min", "5s", "3h").

You can check out other example of tsflex [here](https://github.com/predict-idlab/tsflex/tree/main/examples).

*Disclaimer: This library was created by me and some colleagues.*

Comment: if you created the library you _must_ disclose affiliation in the answer